# Webscraping an html div tag with style element

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the content of the following `div` tag:

```
<div style="font-weight:normal">

<h3> PROYECTO DE LEY </h3> <br>

 <strong>Expediente </strong>4893-D-2007<br>
 <strong>Sumario: </strong>LEY DE EDUCACION SUPERIOR: PRINCIPIOS 
 GENERALES, ESTRUCTURA Y ARTICULACION, DE LOS INSTITUTOS DE EDUCACION 
 SUPERIOR, DE LOS TITULOS Y PLANES DE ESTUDIO, ORGANOS DE GOBIERNO, 
 EDUCACION SUPERIOR A DISTANCIA, DEROGACION DE LA LEY 24521.<br>
<strong>Fecha: </strong><br>                       

 </div>
```

using `rvest` in R. I have the following code so far:

```
link <- 
read_html(paste0("https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/proyectoTP.jsp? 
exp=4893-D-2007"))
  type <- html_nodes(link, 'h3')
  type_text <- html_text(type)


  table <-html_node(link, "table.table.table-bordered tbody")

  table_text <- html_text(table)

  table_text <- gsub("\n", "", table_text)
  table_text <- gsub("\t", "", table_text)
  table_text <- gsub("", "", table_text)

  #this is the relevant part of the code that attempts to capture the 
  style css selector

  billsum <- html_node(link, style*='font-weight:normal')
  billsum_text <- html_text(billsum)
```

I'm not really sure what's happening with the code or if there's a better way to scrape this information, but I'd really like to be able to scrape the sumario and fecha content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the "Sumario" content you can do

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/proyectoTP.jsp?exp=4893-D-2007"

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_text() %>%
  gsub("\t|\n", "", .) %>%
  sub(".*Sumario:(.*)\\.Fecha:.*", "\\1", .)

#[1] " LEY DE EDUCACION SUPERIOR: PRINCIPIOS GENERALES, ESTRUCTURA Y ARTICULACION,
#   DE LOS INSTITUTOS DE EDUCACION SUPERIOR, DE LOS TITULOS Y PLANES DE ESTUDIO,
#   ORGANOS DE GOBIERNO, EDUCACION SUPERIOR A DISTANCIA, DEROGACION DE LA LEY 24521"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the html_node() function you can choose the relevant css part, which in your case is ".interno div". I recommend using "SelectorGadget" for Google Chrome. There you can click on specific parts of a webpage and exclude others to know which one you want.

```
link <- 
read_html(paste0("https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/proyectoTP.jsp?exp=4893-D-2007"))

billsum <- html_node(link, ".interno div")
billsum_text <- html_text(billsum)
```

Comment: After that you need to clean the string, as the other answerer did below with billsum_text %>%
  gsub("\t|\n", "", .)